# How to solve this error: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'write_audiofile'

Tags: python, audio, video, ffmpeg, moviepy

```
import moviepy.editor
# Replace the parameter with the location of the video


video = moviepy.editor.VideoFileClip("/home/amit/video2.mp4")
audio = video.audio


# Replace the parameter with the location along with filename
audio.write_audiofile("/home/amit/output.mp3")
```

This is the code and getting this error:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'write_audiofile'
```

Comment: `video.audio` is `None`, and you're not checking for it being `None`, hence the error. You need to figure out why it's `None`, and also put a guard for that in your code so it doesn't throw an error. `audio` is set only if the video clip has audio detected in it; have you verified that the code works for other videos? It's possible the video you're using does not have audio, or at least readable audio. What format is the audio in? See [here](https://www.remosoftware.com/info/know-codecs-videos-clips) for info on how to find out. VLC can also show this info.

Comment: good point @RandomDavis , for example, my webcam videos that recorded always making this error

Answer (score 2):

It appears that the value of video.audio is None, which is python's null value.

Null values do not have any attributes, so you are getting an AttributeError when attempting to access an attribute that doesn't exist.

In this specific case, this may mean that moviepy was not able to find audio in video2.mp4.

You may be able to get more info by calling the following:

```
print(video.reader.infos)
```